# Making a barchart where each column of the dataframe becomes a separate bar

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I am looking to find a way to make a data frame that has each column a different group, to be a bar. The values below is are the data points for that respective group.

Goal: to make a bar chart with mean standard error with the marker plots on... I tried to put mean standard error bars on them, with each data point being labeled on the bar chart as well, but currently, I am facing with the issue of being able to plot the bars.

I looked on other stackoverflows, and other ggplot2 resources online for this. I'm not sure why I am blanking out on this...

In the column category, there are three groups that I would like to make a bar plot for. The ratio column has the data points.

```
category <- c("c1", "d1", "ff", "ff", "d1", "d1", "c1", "c1")
ratio <- c(3,2,5,6,1,1.5, 4, 4.5)

df <- data.frame(category, ratio)
```

I would appreciate any advice on this please! Thank you

Comment: Could you please show (at least draw) the deired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These can be tricky. `geom_bar()` by default just counts things in a single variable, and `geom_col()` by default draws bars for each y value you supply it, and also stacks them on top of each other with its `position = "stack"` default argument.

This basic method below has served me well and allows you to keep the data in long format with the measurements for each replicate.

Instead of `geom_col()`, we use `stat_summary()` to take the means of the y aesthetic and then we specify `geom = "col"`. We do similarly for the errorbars. In these `stat_` functions, we can use `fun` for a single y aesthestic (as needed for `geom_col`) or we can use `fun.data` to return `ymin`, `y`, and `ymax`, as called for by `geom_errorbar()`. `ggplot2::mean_se()` is a function meant specifically for `stat_summary()` which returns these three values.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = category, y = ratio)) +
    stat_summary(
        geom = "col",
        fun = mean
    ) +
    stat_summary(
        geom = "errorbar",
        fun.data = mean_se,
    ) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

This is somewhat ugly by default. We can spice it up by adding a `fill` aesthetic to the bars, jitter to the points, and other visual details.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = category, y = ratio)) +
    stat_summary(
        aes(fill = category),
        geom = "col",
        fun = mean,
        width = 0.85,
        color = "black"
    ) +
    stat_summary(
        geom = "errorbar",
        fun.data = mean_se,
        width = 0.5,
        linewidth = 0.5
    ) +
    geom_point(
        shape = 21,
        size = 2,
        fill = "white",
        position = position_jitter(width = 0.2)
    ) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a `barplot` of group-`mean`s and `sd` added as error bars. Use `tapply` for aggregation, `barplot` for the bars and `arrows` for error bars.

```
> a <- sapply(c(mean, sd), \(f) with(df, tapply(ratio, category, f)))
> b <- barplot(a[, 1], ylim=c(0, max(rowSums(a))), col='black', ylab='foo')
> arrows(b, a[, 1], b, rowSums(a), length=.1, angle=90)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(category = c("c1", "d1", "ff", "ff", "d1", "d1", 
"c1", "c1"), ratio = c(3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 1.5, 4, 4.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```